# Why I get an error when implementing this easy hash for vector <int>?

Tags: c++, vector, unordered-map

I'm writing a program where I need to hash 10 elements and keep an int for every `vector<int>`.

So I've declared the `undordered_map` like this :

```
struct myhash {
    size_t operator()(const vector<int>& v) const {
        size_t value = 1;
        for (auto x: v) {
            value = value * P + hash<int>()(x);
        }
        return value;
    }
};
tr1::unordered_map < vector <int>, int, myhash > H;
```

I get this errors in struct myhash :

```
expected initializer before ':' token
expected  primary-expression before 'return'
expected ';' before 'return'
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: Your compiler doesn't speak C++11.

Comment: What compiler are you using? Did you run in it C++11 mode?

Comment: You need to enable C++11, change compiler or avoid using range-based `for`s and new `auto` semantics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently your compiler has either

- ...its C++11 support not enabled. GCC and Clang do this via `-std=c++11`.
- ...no support for range-based for at all. In this case you have to stick to a traditional loop using iterators instead.

  ```
  for (std::vector<int>::const_iterator iter = v.begin();
       iter != v.end(); ++iter)
  {
      value = value * P + hash<int>()(*iter);
  }
  ```